# More efficient matrix-vector product

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Dear mathematica users,

In my present research I am faced with a real dense $n\times n$ matrix $A$ where $n \geq 3000$ (hopefully even more). The coefficients of this matrix are fixed, but I will have to repeatedly multiply it by a variable vector: $Ax$.

I am not complaining about Mathematica's speed to do the job, which seems quite nice, but since I will need to do this repeatedly for very many times, I was wondering if there was a way to optimise the process. Perhaps, declaring it in a With will help, but besides that I am out of ideas.

Another alternative would be a low-rank approximation using SVD. My thoughts were: with the SVD I can write 
\begin{equation}
A = \sigma_1 u_1 v_1^\text{T} + \sigma_2 u_2 v_2^\text{T} + \ldots
\end{equation}
so 
\begin{equation}
Ax = (\sigma_1 v_1^\text{T}x) u_1  + (\sigma_2 v_2^\text{T})u_2  + \ldots
\end{equation}
As an example, using a rank 100 approximation to a $3000\times 3000$ matrix (which yields a Frobenius error of $\sim5-10\;\%$) I was able to reduce the computation time by a factor of roughly 3 or 4.

I thank in advance for any positive feedback.

Best regards,

Gabriel Landi

**Edit:** Forgot to say that $A$ is symmetric and has zero diagonal.

Comment: Do you have a graphics card that supports [CUDA](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CUDALink/guide/CUDALink.html) or [OpenCL](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/OpenCLLink/guide/OpenCLLink.html)? I've found [CUDADot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CUDALink/ref/CUDADot.html) to be very fast even with a pretty weak graphics card.

Comment: @ssch the CUDA part of `CUDADot` is very fast, but depending on the problem the overhead for a call can make it slower than a standard `Dot`.

Comment: @YvesKlett You are right. I did some testing and I was mistaken, only with matrix-matrix multiplication was there a real advantage. Do you know more than one of the `x` vectors at a time so you can put them in a matrix?

Comment: Improving the speed of this product will be extremely difficult since it is already highly optimized. The only way I can think of apart from CUDA is a direct call to [``LinearAlgebra`BLAS`GEMV``](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/mklman/GUID-25178576-05F1-4A33-8A0E-3694F0CCD242.htm).

Comment: Does `A` have a full rank? If so, can you work in its eigenspace? Alternatively, can you calculate $A X$ where $X = (\begin{matrix}\vec{x}_1&\vec{x}_2&\cdots\end{matrix})$, instead? That would allow you to use CUDA with full matrix-matrix computations, and the eigenspace idea is still applicable.

Comment: Hi all. Sorry for the delay in answering. Yes, $A$ will usually have full rank. It is also symmetric and has zero diagonal. But I don't know all the $x$'s in advance, so I need one dot product at a time. Thank you all for the support.

Comment: @GabrielLandi well a symmetric matrix definitely makes it easier. Then, can you generate your $\vec{x}_i$ in the eigenspace of $A$? If not, is $A$ amenable to some other form of [symmetry reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_representation) that you can exploit in generating your $\vec{x}_i$? Possibly their [spherical components](http://books.google.com/books?id=r4GIU2wJCAEC&pg=PA126&dq=spherical+components+tinkham&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aIP1UKqwIvKy0QGB-4HQDg&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=spherical%20components%20tinkham&f=false)?

Comment: @rcollyer What exactly do you mean by generating in eigenspace: if $A = S \Lambda S^{-1}$ then I should do $Ax = S \Lambda S^{-1} x$? Also, I read your link on spherical components, but didn't really get how that would translate to the present problem. Again, thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes you can calculate $Ax = S\Lambda S^{-1}x$, but if $x$ is already in terms of the basis of $A$, then $Ax$ reduces to `{a11, a22, ...} {x1, x2, ...}` which is very fast. But, I think your likely only to get a speed up, if $x$ is already in that basis. If $x$ isn't easily expressible in the basis of $A$, then it may be expressible in either terms of the group representations of $A$ or, barring that, as spherical components. Either way would reduce the computational load, if set up right. But, it depends on how $x$ is generated.

Comment: Mostly, I'm just grasping at straws. The best bet would of course be to express $x$ in the basis of $A$, then there is nothing special you have to do, and it will be very fast. The other two ideas require a bit of work, which may not give you the speed up to make them worth it.

Comment: Related question: [Efficiently Constructing Rank One Approximations for a Matrix using SVD](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8338/245)

Comment: @Jens Actually, I asked that question :)

Comment: Anything else about the $x_{i}$? For example, $x_{i+1}=x_{i} + dx_{i}$ where $dx_{i}$ is small? Easily decompose $x_{i}$ into previous values of $x$? Just spitballing...

Answer (score 4):

SVD is an $O(n^3)$ operation (and truncated rank-$r$ factorization is probably still of complexity $O(r \, n^2)$, so pretty slow. If your matrix `A` has indeed low rank $r \ll n$, then [*Adaptive Cross Approximation (ACA)*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/PL00005410) can provide a rank-$r$ factorization in $O(r^2 \, n)$ time and $O(r \, n)$ additional memory. This algorithm is greedy, so you can prescibe a given relative accucary and it will find also the required rank $r$. The resulting factors usually have a size that is only insignificantly larger than the factors provided by truncated SVD. The method is also very powerful because it needs only a few columns and rows of the matrix $A$ so that $A$ *does not need to be fully assembled in memory*. If course, it is not 100% reliable: Think of a sparse matrix with few nonzero rows and columns; these will quite certainly not be detected. But it works greate provided that the matrix $A$ is *sufficiently smooth*, (i.e., if it originates from sampling a smooth integral kernel $K(x,y)$),

Here is an example with a 400-fold speedup. It features a squared distance matrix `A` which *really* has (numerically) low rank ($r \leq 6$). Please find the code for `ACACompression` [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/189913).

```
n = 5000;
A = DistanceMatrix[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 3}]]^2;
u = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n}];

{U, V} = ACACompression[A, "MaxRank" -> 150, "Tolerance" -> 1. 10^-12]
U = Transpose[U];

u = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n}];
btrue = A.u; // RepeatedTiming // First
bproxy = U.(V.u); // RepeatedTiming // First

Max[Abs[btrue - bproxy]]
```

> 0.0080
>
> 0.000019
>
> 6.25278*10^-13

The factorization took `0.0042` seconds. For comparision: `SingularValueDecomposition[A]` took `23.6235` seconds on my machine.