# Nearest Kronecker Product

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, tensors, code-request

Some people (see [*The ubiquitous Kronecker product* by Van Loan](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0377-0427(00)00393-9)) have worked on finding two matrices $\mathbf A$,$\mathbf B$ of specified size whose tensor product $\mathbf A\otimes\mathbf B$ is closest (in a norm) to a given (larger) matrix $\mathbf C$. That is, find $\mathbf A$,$\mathbf B$ which minimizes $\|\mathbf C−\mathbf A\otimes\mathbf B\|$. The algorithm is based on the SVD. There is a MATLAB implementation [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/aflorenc/research/nikp.html). It would be nice to see this algorithm implemented in *Mathematica* (using SVD, Riffle...)

Has anyone done this?

Possible Extensions are:

- Factorisation - If the error is zero then the algorithm factorises the original matrix.
- Find the nearest Kronecker product over all possible smaller matrices.
- The algorithm uses the Frobenius norm - could other norms be used?

Comment: BTW does anyone know about factoring exactly? What about different norms?

Comment: "factoring exactly?" - Pitsianis-Van Loan already covers that. See my first example.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [Pitsianis-Van Loan algorithm](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-94-015-8196-7_17) turns out to be surprisingly easy to implement in *Mathematica*:

```
nearestKroneckerProductSum[mat_?MatrixQ, dim1_?VectorQ, dim2_?VectorQ,
                           k_Integer?Positive, opts___] /; 
      TrueQ[Dimensions[mat] == dim1 dim2] := Module[{tmp},
      Check[tmp =
            SingularValueDecomposition[Flatten[Partition[mat, dim2], {{2, 1}, {4, 3}}],
                                       k, opts], 
            Return[$Failed], SingularValueDecomposition::take];
      MapThread[#1 MapThread[Composition[Transpose, Partition],
                             {#2, {dim1, dim2}[[All, 1]]}] &,
                {Sqrt[Diagonal[tmp[[2]]]], Transpose[Transpose /@ Delete[tmp, 2]]}]]

nearestKroneckerProduct[mat_?MatrixQ, dim1_?VectorQ, dim2_?VectorQ, opts___] /;
      TrueQ[Dimensions[mat] == dim1 dim2] := 
      First[nearestKroneckerProductSum[mat, dim1, dim2, 1, opts]]
```

To verify the routine, let's use a manifest Kronecker product as an example:

```
dim1 = {4, 3}; dim2 = {6, 5};
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42];
            m1 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, dim1]; m2 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, dim2]];
tst = KroneckerProduct[m1, m2];
{t1, t2} = nearestKroneckerProduct[tst, dim1, dim2];
Norm[KroneckerProduct[t1, t2] - tst, "Frobenius"] // Chop
   0
```

Note, however, that `t1` and `t2` are not the same as `m1` and `m2`, since the factorization is only unique up to a constant factor.

Now, for an actual random matrix:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42]; m3 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, dim1 dim2]];
{bm, cm} = nearestKroneckerProduct[m3, dim1, dim2];
Norm[KroneckerProduct[bm, cm] - m3, "Frobenius"]
   9.853962754011258
```

---

As can be ascertained from the implementation given above, the Pitsianis-Van Loan algorithm can in fact solve a more general problem; namely, to express a matrix as a sum of Kronecker products. The underlying algorithm relies on constructing a certain matrix through shuffling the original, and then proceeding to derive a [low-rank approximation via SVD](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8338), which can then be reshuffled into the Kronecker factors of the terms.

To demonstrate, here is the algorithm applied to `m3`, and trying to express it as a sum of six Kronecker products:

```
k = 6;
tx = nearestKroneckerProductSum[m3, dim1, dim2, k];
Norm[m3 - Total[KroneckerProduct @@@ tx], "Frobenius"]
   5.6710996859350775
```

Comment: Nice! That seems like a fairly general and useful function.

Comment: Great. Thanks for that!

Comment: A little confession: the implementation in this answer is actually just a special case of the algorithm; in full generality, the algorithm solves the problem of expressing a matrix as a *sum* of Kronecker products. In that general case, one just takes multiple singular vectors, from which one can then build the required matrices .

Comment: @J.M. Would you be willing to post an implementation of the full algorithm if it's not too much work for you? On this post or a new one, either way. That would actually be pretty useful for things that I do.

Comment: @march, if you don't mind waiting for a few days, sure... :)

Comment: @J.M. That would be great, thanks! No rush, obviously! Do you think you'll post a new self-answered question or will you update this answer?

Comment: @march, have you seen the generalized routine already?

Comment: @J.M. Thank you for the update! I had not seen it. I do theoretical quantum mechanics calculations for part of my living, and systems with multiple degrees of freedom are treated using tensor-products of the different spaces associated with these dof's, and so this kind of decomposition can be useful for me. Thanks again! I'm awarding a bounty as a token of my appreciation.

Comment: @march, you're welcome; it was actually fun to write, and it helped that the paper described the algorithm very clearly.

Comment: looks like I have a couple of papers to read. :)

Comment: Very interesting from an image compression standpoint too if `m3` is a grayscale image of dimensions {n^2,n^2} and `dim1,dim2` are both dimension `{n,n}`.